# String Verifier char loop wont work properly

Tags: c++, string, loops, verification

I can't get my password verify program to work. My loop seems to only iterate once, I just put "it" as output to see if it's constantly iterating, but its not. I'm not sure why, the booleans are working, but it just iterates once, and if my first letter is a lowercase, then it'll say I need an uppercase and a digit, and vice-versa if my first character is a digit or uppercase. This is a homework assignment, but I'm a little lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cctype>



using namespace std; 


int main()
{
    const int LENGTH = 20;
    char pass[LENGTH];



    cout << "Enter a password, that's at least 6 characters long, one uppercase, one lowercase letter ";
    cout << " and one digit." << endl;
    cin.getline(pass,LENGTH);



    bool isdig = true;
    bool isdown = true;
    bool isup = true;
    bool correct = false; 





    for(int index = 0; correct == false; index++)
    {
        cout << "it" << endl;

        if(isupper(pass[index]) == 0)
        {isup = false;}

        if(islower(pass[index]) == 0)
        {isdown = false;}

        if(isdigit(pass[index]) == 0)
        {isdig = false;}



        if(isdig == true && isup == true && isdown == true)
        {correct = true;}



        if(index = LENGTH - 1)
        {
            if(isdig == false)
            {cout << "Your password needs a digit." << endl;}

            if(isup == false)
            {cout << "Your password needs an uppercase letter." << endl;}

            if(isdown == false)
            {cout << "Your password needs a lowercase letter." << endl;}

            cout << "Re-enter another password. " << endl;
            cin.getline(pass,LENGTH);

            index = 0;
            isdown = true;
            isup = true;
            isdig = true;
        }

    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: have you tried using a debugger? I see you're running MVS...

Comment: nah I haven't let me try edit: ive used the local windows debugger in mvs

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably this line:

```
if(index = LENGTH - 1)
```

Here you *assign* the value of `LENGTH - 1` to `index`, so you are always asked to re-enter your password as that expression always is true.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable your compiler warning (-Wall if you are using g++) and pay attention to the warnings:

```
es.cpp:52:30: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
```

This tells you that some condition `(a==b)` as probably been written as `(a=b)` which is an assignment. And indeed

```
if(index = LENGTH - 1)
```

should be written

```
if (index == LENGTH - 1)
```

Also for readability

```
if(isdig == true && isup == true && isdown == true)
```

could be replaced by

```
if (isdig and isup and isdown)
```

and

```
if(isdig == false)
```

by

```
if (not isdig)
```

Comment: That may be why im getting the runtime errors when i run it in microsoft visual studio